# Why does this VBA code for SQL queries on CSV files work intermittently?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, csv, ado

A very simple query function that takes in a path for a source CSV file and a SQL statement as a string (I'm also transposing the data from the VBA function),

```
Public Function RunQuery(FilePath As String, SQLStatement As String)

    Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim RecSet As New ADODB.Recordset

    With Conn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & FilePath & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;IMEX=1"""
    End With

    Conn.Open
    RecSet.Open SQLStatement, Conn
    RecSet.MoveFirst
    RunQuery = RecSet.GetRows()

    Conn.Close
    Set RecSet = Nothing
    Set Conn = Nothing

End Function
```

This code works intermittently against a CSV files, some data is retrieved correctly and some is not.

An example are these two CSV files - [Abbreviated](http://pastebin.com/1HdYZnn9) and [Full](http://pastebin.com/dLHyuFNb). The following SQL query works perfectly on the Abbreviated file, but returns #VALUE on the Full file.

```
SELECT birthYear FROM [File]
```

It's definitely not a data limit/size issue as the Full file only contains 1800 rows. I'm completely befuddled and would appreciate any thoughts/pointers.

Incidentally if I wrap up the logic into a Sub rather than a UDF then it works perfectly without any errors,

```
Public Sub RunQuerySub()

Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim RecSet As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim FilePath As String
FilePath = ActiveSheet.Range("Path")

With Conn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & FilePath & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;IMEX=1"""
End With
Dim SQLStatement As String
SQLStatement = ActiveSheet.Range("SQL")

Conn.Open
RecSet.Open SQLStatement, Conn
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 8).CopyFromRecordset RecSet

Conn.Close
Set RecSet = Nothing
Set Conn = Nothing

End Sub
```

I am very confused, and would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Where does it return `#VALUE`? Your code only assigns an array, *RunQuery* to recordset rows.

Comment: If I set a breakpoint at the last `Set Conn = Nothing` line, then `RunQuery` shows a Variant array in the Watch window, which contains the full list of results. But for some reason it returns #VALUE to the sheet itself. As mentioned, this issue only occurs with the larger file, not the smaller one.

Comment: Are you using this as a UDF in a worksheet?   If you try calling it from a Sub you will get more-useful error messages.

Comment: Ok, now I am completely confused. Running the same query on the large file as a Sub worked. Running it as a UDF throws a #VALUE.

Comment: When defined as a function, how are you getting it on to the excel page? I guess Excel just doesn't support the passing of a variant array on to a page via a function

Comment: It does. I simply call `=RunQuery(<Path>, <SQL>)'. As mentioned above this works perfectly for one file, but not the other. Very easy for you to try yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adapted the technique for using a `Sub` and managed to get a `Function` which returns an array for both abbreviated and full files.

Highlight a range of 1892 cells in a column & use this array function

```
=RunQuery("C:\stackoverflow", "SELECT birthYear FROM [full.csv]")
```

This is the function. It replaces `Null` values in the resultset with zero.

```
Public Function RunQuery(FilePath As String, SQLStatement As String)

    Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim RecSet As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rows As Variant
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    With Conn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & FilePath & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;IMEX=1"""
    End With

    Conn.Open
    RecSet.Open SQLStatement, Conn
    RecSet.MoveFirst
    rows = RecSet.GetRows()

    Conn.Close
    Set RecSet = Nothing
    Set Conn = Nothing

    Dim nrows As Integer, i As Integer, valu As Integer
    nrows = UBound(rows, 2) + 1
    ReDim arr2(1 To nrows, 1 To 1) As Integer
    For i = 1 To nrows
        If IsNull(rows(0, i - 1)) Then
            valu = 0
        Else
            valu = rows(0, i - 1)
        End If
        arr2(i, 1) = valu
    Next
    RunQuery = arr2
    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
    Resume Next
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, John. You hit the nail on the head - the output Variant arrays didn't like the null values. Will adapt your solution of replacing those records. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

When I suggested running it from a Sub I didn't really mean *as* a Sub.

I meant do something like below, where your function is unchanged and the only difference is you're running it from VBA instead of as a UDF.

When running from VBA you will be able to see any errors instead of just getting #VALUE in a worksheet cell.

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim arr
    arr = RunQuery("yourPath", "yourSQL")
End sub


Public Function RunQuery(FilePath As String, SQLStatement As String)

    Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim RecSet As New ADODB.Recordset

    With Conn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & FilePath & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;IMEX=1"""
    End With

    Conn.Open
    RecSet.Open SQLStatement, Conn
    RecSet.MoveFirst
    RunQuery = RecSet.GetRows()

    Conn.Close
    Set RecSet = Nothing
    Set Conn = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks like the problem is VBA doesn't like the NULL values contained in some columns in the results returned from the query.

Answer (score 0):

This button click event handler produced the results by calling `RunQuerySub`. Three input parameters are defined in B2, B3. B4.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim FilePath As String, SQLStatement As String, TargetColumn As String
    FilePath = Sheet1.Range("B2").Text
    SQLStatement = Sheet1.Range("B3").Text
    TargetColumn = Sheet1.Range("B4").Text
    Call RunQuerySub(FilePath, SQLStatement, TargetColumn)
End Sub
```

The subroutine is much as you had it, but there were some Null values which caused issues with assigning to a Range object, so I replaced these with zeroes. The resultset from RecSet.GetRows() is a 2D variant array with the birthYear values in the 2nd dimension. I assigned these to an array with the values in the first dimension so it would populate the range by row.

Functions don't appear to allow you to assign values to ranges - at any rate I could not find a way of doing it.

```
Public Sub RunQuerySub(FilePath As String, SQLStatement As String, TargetColumn As String)

    Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim RecSet As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rows As Variant
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    With Conn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & FilePath & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;IMEX=1"""
    End With

    Conn.Open
    RecSet.Open SQLStatement, Conn
    RecSet.MoveFirst
    rows = RecSet.GetRows()

    Conn.Close
    Set RecSet = Nothing
    Set Conn = Nothing

    Dim dest As Range
    Dim nrows As Integer, i As Integer, valu As Integer
    nrows = UBound(rows, 2) + 1
    ReDim arr2(1 To nrows, 1 To 1) As Integer
    For i = 1 To nrows
        If IsNull(rows(0, i - 1)) Then
            valu = 0
        Else
            valu = rows(0, i - 1)
        End If
        arr2(i, 1) = valu
    Next
    Dim rangeDefn As String
    rangeDefn = TargetColumn & "1:" & TargetColumn & CStr(nrows)
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set dest = .Range(rangeDefn)
    End With
    dest = arr2
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
    Resume Next
End Sub
```